# How to solve "Report item not linked to Dataset" error in RDLC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I am using Visual studio 2010 and i have created a rdlc report without using report wizard and added the dataset to it but when i right click on a textbox,choose expression and then navigate to datasets i could see my dataset added to report but when i click on the fields it shows "Report item not linked to a dataset". I not facing this issue in VS 2008 and the report works correctly in it. I don't know how to solve this issue in VS2010. So somebody help me regarding this issue. I have attached the screenshot of the issue below. Please check it.

[image: Fields not populated by dataset]

[image: Error when using Dataset]

The code i used to display values in table is given below but i would like to know how to display the values in textboxes instead of table.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LocalReport lr = null;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select CatalogNo as CatalogNo, Productname as ProductName, Quality_Plan_Ref_No as QPRefNo,Drawing_No as DrawingNo,ISR_No as ISRNo,BatchNo as BatchNo,Allotted_Qty as AllottedQty,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Allotted_Date,105) as AllottedDate from Batch_Allott where CatalogNo='0464' ", con);
    da.Fill(ds, "temp");
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    lr = ReportViewer1.LocalReport;
    lr.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
    lr.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Dataset1_Batch_Allott", ds.Tables[0]));
}
```

Comment: you can use =First(Fields!CatalogNo.Value,"DataSetName") because i think your textbox is not in Tablix or ListView so you have to reference dataset via an aggregate expression

Comment: @Sandeep why there is a red line appearing when i use your suggested instruction. See my updated image in the question.

Comment: i am not sure why it is showing red line may be because of Semantic Error but it will work if you run the report

Comment: @Sandeep I have a list of dates in to Allotted_Date and i have to show a particular date based on the catalogno which i pass through query.Can u explain how to do this along with the sample code.

Comment: i am assuming that when you filter by catalogno then final result in dataset will have only 1 row. In this case you can use First but if dataset contains multiple row then you have to use Tablix or ListView or you have to use other aggregate  function like Min, Max, Avg etc.

Comment: @Sandeep Check my code in the question and correct the code for me to display the values in textboxes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66006/discussion-between-sandeep-and-ezhilan).

Answer (score 9):

Select the `Tablix` and then right click on the left top Square. Select `Tablix Properties`.

In the `Tablix Properties` window make sure you have your `Dataset` name selected.

I ran into this problem after I deleted the previous `Dataset` and it was left blank. If you don't see one in the dropdown you might need to go to `View|Report Data` and `Refresh` it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the dataset for the rdlc report. In report design you can configure the dataset fields.

You can find the configuration option in View -> Report Data

If you have already added the dataset for this, there is other case that you have to refresh the dataset if you modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Report item is inside a Tablix item. Then you can follow the steps for asigning a Dataset to that Tablix.

After that, you will see your report item linked to the same Dataset as your Tablix item.

Answer (score 0):

Select The Row Which You Need To Add Your Logic to it.
The Fileds(DataSet) Will Be appeared.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).